# $e^{iBt}e^{-iAt}$converges as operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A,B$ be self-adjoint operators on $H$,then we can define the strong limit
$$
W=s-\lim_{t\to+\infty}e^{iBt}e^{-iAt}
$$
If the limit exists, then W is called the wave operator, which is fundamental in the scattering theory. My question here is that if instead, we consider the operator norm above,then what can be said about it ? I was told that the the limit exists if and only if $A=B$, but I don't know how to prove this statement.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ commute, you get $e^{iBt}e^{-iAt}=e^{i(B-A)t}$. If $B-A\neq 0$, take a nonzero eigenvalue and a nonzero eigenvector to see that the strong limit does not exist, therefore the operator norm limit does not exist. When $A$ and $B$ do not commute, it is less easy...

Comment: @1015: I'm having the same problem. ^^